# Where can i get a good free css editor?

Tags: css, django

Am developing my web application using Django, and is seems CSS is the only way i can format my pages to look and feel nice. Where can i get a free and good css editor?

NB: Is there another way to format forms in Django?

Answer (score 2):

Cool stuff for Eclipse...

http://aptana.com/studio

Answer (score 2):

This is not so much about editing, but the ultimate tool for CSS debugging:

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843) Firefox Plugin

Comment: i've yet to find a better way to get my pages to look right than fiddling CSS with Firebug

Answer (score 1):

[TopStyle Lite](http://www.newsgator.com/individuals/topstyle/default.aspx) is a nice editor. It does not have full blown IDE- and debugger capabilities, but it has a few touches:

- lightweight, loads fast, like a text editor
- pre-selectable CSS support level to see CSS support in legacy browsers
- has "IntelliSense"-style keyword completion
- you can also point-and-click style rules in an "inspector" pane, plus there's a "css selector"-wizard
- colors can be selected from a palette

Answer (score 1):

Fresh from Lifehacker: [CSS Toolbox Is a Killer Text Editor for Web Designers](http://lifehacker.com/5073005/css-toolbox-is-a-killer-text-editor-for-web-designers)

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to format forms but CSS is the best way. I'll second the recommendation for Aptana, and according to Lifehacker [CSS Toolbox](http://lifehacker.com/5073005/css-toolbox-is-a-killer-text-editor-for-web-designers) is also quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really huge fan of [Komodo Edit.](http://www.activestate.com/Products/komodo_ide/komodo_edit.mhtml)

It's free supports syntax highlighting and supports code intelligence. This is the best editor I've ever found.

If you need to ramp up for churning alot of code this will surely save your life.

I liked it so much, I bought the full IDE.

Plus, it's available on every platform.